# C++ Pointer after delete it then give value

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, new-operator, delete-operator

I come up against with this problem, it create 3 block of memory, I'm confuse if delete the *r, is **r still exist or not? should I move **r to *r's position?
do I need another "new int" statement to give value?

```
int t = 5;
int **r;
r = new int *;  //declare pointer  
*r = new int;
delete *r;      // delete pointer
*r = t;         //give new value
```

sorry for ask question with mistake. still learning in it. Thanks.

Comment: if you read the question, it gone be an integer. So I edited it make it more sense

Comment: _"Please do not vote lower without reading."_. The down votes are absolutely deserved. Show a [MCVE] when asking a question! No evidence that `t` is an `int` before you edited your question also.

Comment: sorry, my bad, fixed it

Comment: And do not use raw pointers and `new` in c++. There's `std::unique_ptr` which will do the memory management correctly for you.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll remember it. But its CS2 class's lab, I guess I have no choice.

Comment: _"I guess I have no choice."_ Well, one is to kick your professors ass, for teaching such silly stuff.

Comment: lol, thanks man, you make my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct ([Ideone](https://ideone.com/Lajyz5)):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int **r = new int *; // declare pointer to int*
    cout << r << endl;   // outputs some address in memory (pointer to int*)
    cout << *r << endl;  // outputs some garbage value
//  cout << **r << endl; // it's invalid

    *r = new int;        // assign to memory pointed by r new value
    cout << *r << endl;  // outputs some address in memory (pointer to int)
    cout << **r << endl; // outputs some garbage value

    delete *r;           // delete pointer to int
    cout << *r << endl;  // outputs same address in memory, but we can't dereference it
//  cout << **r << endl; // it's invalid, because we deleted *r

    // here you can acces r, *r, but not 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my professor give "**r = new int * ",  I guess it should be "r = new int *"

Comment: @TaihongWang, you can first define variable `r` (`int **r;`) and then assign to it (`r = new int *;`) or you can define and assign in one line (`int **r = new int*`)